# How to iterate over a the attributes of a class, in the order they were defined?

Tags: python, reflection

Python comes with the handy `dir()` function that would list the content of a class for you. For example, for this class:

```
class C:
   i = 1
   a = 'b'
```

`dir(C)` would return

```
['__doc__', '__module__', 'a', 'i']
```

This is great, but notice how the order of `'a'` and `'i'` is now different then the order they were defined in.

How can I iterate over the attributes of C (potentially ignoring the built-in doc & module attributes) in the order they were defined? For the C class above, the would be `'i'` then `'a'`.

Addendum:
- I'm working on some serialization/logging code in which I want to serialize attributes in the order they were defined so that the output would be similar to the code which created the class.

Comment: Why would the order they are defined matter at all? Order is irrelevant in this case. How would you use that info if you could get it?

Comment: Are you serializing the class or instances of the class?  In your example, `a` and `i` are class attributes.  If you mean these to be instance attributes, you should define them in `__init__` using `self.a = 'b'` and `self.i = 1`.

Comment: These are class-level attributes, which aren't as useful as instance variables.  Why are you trying to preserve the order of class attributes?  Wouldn't it be better to preserve the order of instance variables?  Why are you trying to do tricks with class-level variables?

Comment: I'm building a generated class-tailored code that gets injected in the class object. It was then a natural choice to enumerate attribute on a class level. If switching to an instance object will make things easier, I would happily switch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think this is possible in Python 2.x. When the class members are provided to the `__new__` method they are given as a dictionary, so the order has already been lost at that point. Therefore even metaclasses can't help you here (unless there are additional features that I missed).

In Python 3 you can use the new `__prepare__` special method to create an ordered dict (this is even given as an example in [PEP 3115](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3115/)).

Comment: Here's how Django does it (Python 2.x and up):
https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.3.x/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L56

Comment: I haven't used Django yet, but I guess this requires that in each assignment we create a new `Field` instance? Sounds like a good solution.

Comment: Yes, that's what Django does.

Answer (score 2):

I'm new in python, so my solution may be not effective

```
class Q:
def __init__(self):
    self.a = 5
    self.b = 10

if __name__ == "__main__":
    w = Q() 
    keys = w.__dict__.keys()
    for k in keys:
        print "Q.%s = %d"%(k,w.__dict__[k])
```

Output is:

```
Q.a = 5
Q.b = 10
```

Comment: This does not preserve the order.

Answer (score 2):

put this method in your class

```
def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
    if attr not in dir(self):
        if attr == "__ordered_fields__":
            super.__setattr__(self, attr, value)
        else:
            if not hasattr(self, "__ordered_fields__"):
                setattr(self, "__ordered_fields__", [])
            self.__ordered_fields__.append(attr)
            super.__setattr__(self, attr, value)
```

and to get the fields in order, just do something like:

```
print(self.__ordered_fields__)
```

Answer (score 1):

This information is not accessible, since attributes are stored in a dict, which is inherently unordered. Python does not store this information about order anywhere.

If you want your serialization format to store things in a certain order you would *specify **that** order explicitly*. You would not use `dir`, which contains things you don't know or care about, you would explicitly provide a list (or whatever) describing what to serialize.