# Iterate of a Class´ attributes

Tags: python, class

there exists following class.

```
class Reaction(object):
    Var1 = "lorem"
    Var2 = "impsum"
    Var3 = "dolor"
```

I'd like to iterate over the attributes of this class, like in following code.

```
for value in Reaction:
    print value
```

This should produce following output.

```
lorem
ipsum
dolor
```

I've already found this topic: [How to iterate over a the attributes of a class, in the order they were defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280961/how-to-iterate-over-a-the-attributes-of-a-class-in-the-order-they-were-defined), but it doesn't really help me.

How can I make my class iterable?

**EDIT**: I thought of something similar like in this post: [Build a Basic Python Iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151/build-a-basic-python-iterator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> for k, v in Reaction.__dict__.iteritems():
...     if not k.startswith('__'):
...         print v
... 
lorem
dolor
impsum
```

Or better:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> class Reaction(object):
...     Var1 = "lorem"
...     Var2 = "impsum"
...     Var3 = "dolor"
...     def __iter__(self):
...         return (v for k, v in inspect.getmembers(self) if not k.startswith('__'))
... 
>>> for value in Reaction():
...     print value
... 
lorem
impsum
dolor
```

Comment: Your code does almost the things I want. But is there no possibility to get it work with `for value in Reaction: print value` (without the `.__dict__` method)?

Comment: @no it isn't - you could however build a helper method returning the class attributes

Comment: @OttoAllmendinger: Could you explain this to me. Is this similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151/build-a-basic-python-iterator?

Comment: @wewa: yes, although there is an easier way (see my answer)

Answer (score 3):

If you really need an object whose members are accessible via dot notation but you still want to iterate through them, you need a [`namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).

```
Reaction = collections.namedtuple('Reaction', ['Var1', 'Var2', 'Var3'])
reaction = Reaction('lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor')
for value in reaction:
    print value
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I use Python version 2.5.1 and there `collections` doesn't have the method `namedtuple`

Answer (score 1):

First off, what you are trying is a little unusual - normally, a `dict` is used for this kind of thing

```
Reaction = {
   var1: "Lorem",
   var2: "Ipsum",
   var3: "Dolor"
}
```

If for some reason you still prefer your method, you can use [inspect.getmembers()](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmembers). A helper function could look like this

```
def attributes(class_):
    for name, value in inspect.getmembers(class_):
        if not name.startswith("__"):
             yield name, value
```

Then you can do

```
for name, value in attributes(Reactor):
    # do stuff
```